# AWS S3 ListBuckets returns all buckets

Tags: node.js, typescript, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have a TypeScript app that [lists a buckets](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/S3.html#listBuckets-property) from an aws-s3. The problem is that the credentials I have are ONLY allowing me to interact (read/write) with a specific ones.

Here's an example:

`ListBuckets` returns `['bucket-1', 'bucket-2', 'bucket-3', 'bucket-4']`

But, my Credentials/ACL allows me to ONLY to read/write with `['bucket-2', 'bucket-4']`

So, How can I list ONLY the buckets that I'm allowed to read/write ?

Here is the code I have:

```
const localS3Object = new AWS.S3();
// ... the localS3Object is initialized with the secrets in here

localS3Object.listBuckets(function(err: AWS.AWSError, data) {
                if (err) {
                    resolve({
                        connected: false,
                        resources: undefined
                    });
                } else {
                    resolve({
                        connected: true,
                        resources: data.Buckets
                    });
                }
            });
```

Comment: Your credentials allow them to list all buckets if that’s what they’re able to do. You probably shouldn’t allow that if that’s not what you want.

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately there isn't really a good way to do what you want to do. The `listBuckets` operation (`ListAllMyBuckets` permission) is an all or nothing operation. The best you can do is filter out the buckets on your own, possibly by trying to take some action (`listObjects` maybe) and seeing if you get a permissions error. Not elegant, by any means.